# How to make code easier to read when using anonymous inner classes in java for Android apps?

Tags: java, android, coding-style

In my experience with Android apps its not too uncommon to see lots anonymous inner classes. Right now I'm working on an auto update feature and have an example of some code below.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    IsUpdateAvailableTask task = new IsUpdateAvailableTask(){

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean updateAvailable) {
            super.onPostExecute(updateAvailable);
            if (updateAvailable) {
                UpdateAvailableDialogFragment dialogFragment = UpdateAvailableDialogFragment.newInstance();
                dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), UpdateAvailableDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName());
                TaskFragment.updateDialogShown = true;
            }
        }

    };

    task.execute(mParameters.getHostUrl(), mParameters.getPackageName(), mParameters.getVersionName());
}
```

My problem with this approach is that code hadoukens become very frequent making it harder to just look at the code. I was wondering if there are any ways to improve readability of the code to reduce the hadouken or at least break it up. Lambdas would not work in this case due to the async task not being an interface.

Comment: How writing to older api level prevents you from using lambdas?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood why I couldn't use lambdas. Made the fix in the question.

Comment: As shmakova answered, you can still use lambdas even if you write a library. If you still don't want to, there is no magic bullet, instead of your example code you can do: 1. make `task` a field. 2. Use an inner class 3. Use a local class. 4. Create `task` in a method. Probably some other options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambdas in library code.
For it you can use [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) gradle plugin or you can use new Android Studio 3.0, where features of java 8 has already supported. Jack was deprecated this spring.